# Cannot destructure property `styles` of 'undefined' on Ionic serve --devapp

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

When trying to run `ionic serve --devapp`, I've got this error:

```
[ng] Cannot destructure property 'styles' of 'undefined' or 'null'.
[ng] TypeError: Cannot destructure property `styles` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
[ng]  at Object.getCommonConfig (.\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\common.js:33:107)
```

I tried to clean npm cache, update all dependencies, delete package-lock.json, and install again. Several times. Tried npm ci also.
Nothing seems to be working.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myludopal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Mazus DEV",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.3.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^4.1.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "android-versions": "^1.4.0",
    "angular4-knob": "^1.1.11",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "cordova": "^9.0.0",
    "cordova-android": "^8.0.0",
    "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "^5.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0",
    "ionic-image-loader": "^7.0.0-beta.2",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.11",
    "ngx-chips": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.13.7",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.7",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.11",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^1.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/lodash-es": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^8.0.3",
    "tslint": "^5.15.0",
    "typescript": "3.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can't find anything specific to this on the web, by looking at the error, it seems like a config file misses a 'style' attribute, I tried to go up the call chain and find what file this was but couldn't do it.

Other build commands workd : `ng serve`, `ng build`, even `ionic cordova build android` works...

The command I'm trying to run is used to test Ionic apps in with devapp android application.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Have you changed your `angular.json` file ?

Comment: I tried to change it after the problem. I generated a new project and compared it with ly current angular.json. There were few differences like a 'configurations' node with 'ci' attribute. Tried to update mine with this but didn't affect my problem :'( Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into the same issue, the problem is not with `ionic` exactly, it's with

`@ionic/angular-toolkit`, I've downgraded it from `1.5.0` to `1.4.0` and everything worked fine again.

The error occurs only if you try to run with livereload mode.

Comment: Worked for me. FYI - logged to the Ionic team here: https://github.com/ionic-team/angular-toolkit/issues/109

Comment: @Haidar Thanks a lot, that was the problem. Also thanks for the issue dotNetkow

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here after update to ionic 4.12 from 4.09.

Solved upgrading to @ionic/angula@latest   (4.2.0)

Comment: This didn't work for me, see other answer about downgrading angular-toolkit (for now, until Ionic team can address whatever is happening)